# webpack 3: how to configure webpack to prevent clashes with other bundles when loaded by another web app?

Tags: javascript, webpack

We have a React app built with Create React App with Typescript and webpack 3 with split chunks. Our app is used in our clients' websites - they load it into their website with a script tag, and then launch it. When our app is launched, it appends a new element to the body, and renders itself into it.

This solution has worked perfectly thus far, but we now have a new client who is experiencing some kind of clash between their bundle and ours upon integration of our module into their website.

The specific error we're seeing is this: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElementNS' of undefined`. This error is coming from the first chunk. I think this is happening because only the first chunk is loaded, not the subsequent one/s, which in turns is probably happening due to a clash between the bundles.

I added the following to our config in an attempt to fix this problem:

```
output: {
    // ...
    jsonpFunction: 'wpJsonpChargeAfter',
}
```

But the bug still persists.

I'm starting to think maybe I need to change something in the `libraryTarget` to prevent the clash. Possibly set it to `umd`?

**So the main question here is: what do I need to change in the webpack config to allow a webpack bundle to run within another web app without any clashes?**

Any help would be appreciated.